# Neural Network does not learn after 50 epochs gives the same training error and same validation error

Tags: keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am working on a computer vision problem which differentiates between forged and original signatures.The inputs to the network are two images
For that I extract features from the 'block3_pool' layer of VGG 16 (shape (None,28,28,256)) and I have created a layer that calculates the square root of the absolute difference of each of the 256 filters of the two images

However the network fails to learn and gives the same training and validation error for every epoch, tweaking the learning rate does not work,changing the architecture does not work. The inputs to the network are two images :anchor and the data whose shapes are (224,224,3)

I have trained it on a very small dataset ,expected it to overfit but the network does not learn even after tinkering the dataset size

Data is of the format, 
for each user there are 24 original and 24 forged signatures.Choosing one randomly from the original set gives the anchor data and choosing randomly between original and forged gives the data array.Thus for each user
I have an anchor array (24 images of the same sample) and the data (24 total images of different original and forged samples) and shape of the anchor and the data array for one user is : (24,224,224,3)

```py
#model hyper parameters ,using sgd optimizer
epochs=50
learning_rate=0.1
decay=learning_rate/epochs
batch_size=8
keep_prob=0.8





#This is the function for lambda layer 'Layer_distance'
def root_diff(x):
    diff=K.sqrt(K.sum(K.abs(x[:,:,:,:,0]-x[:,:,:,:,1]),axis=(1,2)))
    return diff


#This creates an instance of a pre trained VGG-16 model
def base_model(input_dims=(224,224,3),output_dims=128):



 base_model=VGG16(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=input_dims)

 for layers in base_model.layers:
   layers.trainable=False

 x=base_model.get_layer('block3_pool').output



 model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=x)
 return model



def siamese_model(anchor,data,label,anchor_valid,data_valid,label_valid,input_shape=(224,224,3)):

    anchor_input=Input(input_shape)
    data_input=Input(input_shape)



    #----------------------------Model begins from here-------------------------------------------------------#

    model_resnet=base_model(input_dims=input_shape)



    encodings_anchor=model_resnet(anchor_input)
    encodings_data=model_resnet(data_input)








    layer_expand_dims=Lambda(lambda x:K.expand_dims(x,axis=4))





    anchor_expanded=layer_expand_dims(encodings_anchor)
    data_expanded=layer_expand_dims(encodings_data)



    encodings=concatenate([anchor_expanded,data_expanded],axis=4) #gives the shape as (None,28,28,256,2)

    Layer_distance=Lambda(root_diff)(encodings) #Should give a vector of (256)







    dense_1=Dense(256,activation=None,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros')(Layer_distance)


    prediction=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(dense_1)




    # Connect the inputs with the outputs
    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[anchor_input,data_input],outputs=prediction)

    print(siamese_net.summary())

    for layer in siamese_net.layers:
        print("Input shape: "+str(layer.input_shape)+". Output shape: "+str(layer.output_shape))


    sgd= optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-9, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    siamese_net.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])

    history=siamese_net.fit(x=[anchor,data],y=label,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs

                            ,validation_data=([anchor_valid,data_valid],label_valid))
```

The summary of the model (siamese_net)

```py
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 28, 28, 256)  1735488     input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 28, 28, 256,  0           model_1[1][0]                    
                                                                 model_1[2][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 28, 28, 256,  0           lambda_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_1[1][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 256)          0           concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 256)          65792       lambda_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1)            257         dense_1[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,801,537
Trainable params: 66,049
Non-trainable params: 1,735,488
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The training result

```py
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Train on 48 samples, validate on 48 samples
Epoch 1/50
2019-04-21 06:10:00.354542: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
48/48 [==============================] - 4s 90ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 2/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 3/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 4/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 5/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 6/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 7/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 8/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 9/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 10/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 11/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 12/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 13/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 14/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 15/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 16/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 17/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 18/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 19/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 20/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 21/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 22/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 23/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 24/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 25/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 26/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 27/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 28/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 29/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 30/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 31/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 32/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 33/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 34/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 35/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 36/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 37/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 38/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 39/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 40/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 41/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 42/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 43/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 44/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 45/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 46/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 47/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 48/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 49/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 18ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Epoch 50/50
48/48 [==============================] - 1s 19ms/step - loss: 8.9676 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 8.6355 - val_acc: 0.4583
Saved model to disk
```

Answer (score 0):

@Paras doshi

I think you're freezing entire base network. So the training process did not update parameters. You're using the feature vector of third VGG block, so you need to unfreeze at least one of these 3 blocks.

[image]

```sh
def base_model(input_dims=(224,224,3),output_dims=128):



 base_model=VGG16(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=input_dims)

 for layers in base_model.layers:
   layers.trainable=False    <---- Freeze training
```

Hope that help